# Ellipsis not appearing in Typography MUI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to cut off the text if its too long and put an ellipsis on it.
I wonder why this isn't appearing. Is my code wrong or what could we improve?

CODESANDBOX -----> [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-shirley-mnjz5v?file=/Demo.tsx)

```
<Typography
  variant="body2"
  color="black"
  sx={{
    overflow: "hidden",
    textOverflow: "ellipsis",
    display: "-webkit-box",
    WebkitLineClamp: "1",
    WebkitBoxOrient: "vertical"
  }}
>
  femwiofoewjfwjefojweofjwofjoifjoeiwfjoiwejfodqwdqwmodqwopmdoqwdopqwdqwjdpqojd
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css display property not needed there:

```
<Typography
            variant="body2"
            color="black"
            sx={{
              overflow: "hidden",
              textOverflow: "ellipsis",
              WebkitLineClamp: "1",
              WebkitBoxOrient: "vertical"
            }}
          >
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-bessie-tgrylz